# Setting each "curve" on a 3D plot to be of different colour similar to that of its 2D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, map, style

Consider the functions

```
\[Lambda][n_] := ((n \[Pi])/L)^2

\[ScriptCapitalX][
x_] := \[ScriptCapitalC][1] Cos[Sqrt[\[Lambda][n]] x]

\[ScriptCapitalT][t_] := 50 E^(-\[Lambda] t)
```

to give the Sum product solution

```
\[ScriptCapitalU][x_, 
t_, \[ScriptCapitalN]_] := \[ScriptCapitalX][x] \[ScriptCapitalT][t]
```

Notice that the 2D and 3D plot of the Sum product solution, respective are

```
Plot[Evaluate@
ReplaceAll[
Table[\[ScriptCapitalX][x] \[ScriptCapitalT][t], {n, 1, 3}, {L, 1, 
 1}], {\[ScriptCapitalC][1] -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 1, t -> 0}], {x, 0,
1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
PlotLabel -> "2D Plot Behaviour for \[ScriptCapitalU](x,t)"]
```

and

```
Plot3D[ReplaceAll[
Table[\[ScriptCapitalU][x, t, \[ScriptCapitalN]], {n, 1, 3}, {L, 1, 
1}], {\[ScriptCapitalC][1] -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 1}], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 
0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
PlotLabel -> "3D Plot Behaviour for \[ScriptCapitalU](x,t)"]
```

If you rotate the 3D point such that the x and t plots points "towards" you, you are able to observe that they corresponds qualitatively to the 2D plot.

[image]
[image]
In the case of the 3D plot, how do I match the different colours to different "n" for n=1 to n=3?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in `Plot3D[...]` add the options   `Evaluated->True`  or wrap the first argument with `Evaluate` as   you did in `Plot`.

Comment: @kglr It doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@
  ReplaceAll[Table[\[ScriptCapitalU][x, t, \[ScriptCapitalN]], {n, 1, 3}, {L, 1, 1}], 
 {\[ScriptCapitalC][1] -> 1, λ -> 1}], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "3D Plot Behaviour for \[ScriptCapitalU](x,t)"]
```

[image]

**Note:** Interestingly, the combination of options `Evaluated ->True` + `PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}`, which works in version 9, does not work in version 11.2 (on Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: my code bellow works in version 11.2 (PC client).

Answer (score 4):

```
\[Lambda][n_] := ((n \[Pi])/L)^2
\[ScriptCapitalX][x_] := \[ScriptCapitalC][1] Cos[Sqrt[\[Lambda][n]] x]
\[ScriptCapitalT][t_] := 50 E^(-\[Lambda] t)
\[ScriptCapitalU][x_, t_, \[ScriptCapitalN]_] := \[ScriptCapitalX][x] \[ScriptCapitalT][t]

Plot3D[Evaluate@ (* Step 2: enforce the evaluation before configuring the colors *)
  ReplaceAll[Table[\[ScriptCapitalU][x, t, \[ScriptCapitalN]], {n, 1, 3}, {L, 1, 1}], {\[ScriptCapitalC][1] -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 1}], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "3D Plot Behaviour for \[ScriptCapitalU](x,t)",
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}] (* Step 1: use PlotStyle to set up color for each plot surface *)
```

[image]

Comment: how is this different  from the earlier answer below?:)

Comment: @kglr maybe we submit the answer simultaneously... however, I bring out a way to customize the colors by `PlotStyle`. 囧rz

Comment: PureLine, thanks. Good point.